# Where do souls stay until they reincarnate?

Tags: atma, afterlife

I'm certain that they do not reincarnate as soon as they die.

So where do they stay until they reincarnate?

Answer (score 3):

As per the Yogavasistha Ramayana,

> The householders who perform good deeds go to dhumAvimAni devatas, then to rAtri devatAs, then to Krishnapaksha devatAs, then to DakshinAyana devatAs, then to Pitriloka devatAs and ultimately reach **chandra-loka and stay happily** their so long as their bundle of virtues is not exhausted.After that, they again return to the earth via Akasha, Vayu, dhumra and megha.As rain they reach the earth and enter into various corns and when eaten by jivas, they enter into jivas to be born again. (Pranava-prema-piyusha, page 317.

So those who are to be born again  basically resides in the Chandraloka.

Comment: Those who perform good deeds? So I can do a few good deeds and a lot of bad ones and I still get to get to the moon?

Comment: @Wikash_hindu I can quote only what the scriptures say. There are Dhumrayana and Devayana.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu Dont make thinks complicated,Good deed means no bad deeds

Comment: How can one only do good deed. One always also makes bad deeds.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu It is written in Sri Shiva Rahasya in chapter 9, Shivji said - 36.  "Those that are burdened with grievous defects are sent back to Earth sooner.  For in their case there will be much perfecting to accomplish in many a lifetime.  But those that are stained only by slight imperfections abide in the Otherworld for longer.  For only few lifetimes remain for them to dwell upon Earth.  And what is one year in the Otherworld is a hundred upon Earth." I think here otherworld refers to pitrlok. So very bad sinners return early.

Comment: @ShashwatAsthana you do not understand. That is not what the verse says. If you do bad deeds you return early. It does not mention "very bad sinners".